# mongoose model.find in typescript script

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose

I want to write a script to read my old mongoose model and write the data into a new model but if I call the model.find nothing happens.
No error but the first console log prints as expected.
I´m running the script via ts-node.

```
import legacyModel from '../models/legacy/legacyModel';
console.log('▶︎ import Legacy Database')

  legacyModel.find({}, (err, docs) => {
    if (err) { return console.error('❌' + err); }
    console.log('Found ' + docs.length + ' legacy reports');
  })
```

Comment: Have you called `mongoose.connect` somewhere to connect?

Comment: I´m embarrassed - thanks

Comment: No worries, it's a common issue.